# How do I designate a default property for a custom collections class in VBA?

Tags: vba, class, excel, collections

I have a nightmarishly complicated set of Excel macros that I'm trying to simplify by setting up a series of classes, but I haven't ever done object-oriented programming before, so I'm a little unclear as to how to set things up (or even how to formulate my question). I currently have a Lease class which has a Payments property, like so:

```
Option Explicit
Private oPayments As New Payments

Public Property Get Payments() As Payments
Set Payments = oPayments
End Property

Public Property Let Payments(param_Payments As Payments)
Set oPayments = param_Payments
End Property
```

I also have a Payment class, which will hold things like the payment number, and a Payments class, which will hold instances of the Payment class. The Payments class looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Payments As New Collection

Sub Add(param_Number As String)
Dim NewPayment As Payment
Set NewPayment = New Payment
NewPayment.PaymentNumber = param_Number
Payments.Add NewPayment
End Sub

Property Get Count() As Long
Count = Payments.Count
End Property

Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As Payment
Set Item = Payments(Index)
End Property
```

This all works pretty well, but it's a little bit clunky, since in order to specify a payment, I need to use `Lease.Payments.Item(1).PaymentNumber`. How could I set things up so I could just use `Lease.Payments(1).PaymentNumber`? Better yet, since there's only one lease per worksheet, can I set it up so that I just say `Payments(1).PaymentNumber` and it defaults to the lease on the active sheet, the way that built-in objects like Range do? I could just rename "Payments" as "Lease" and "Item" as "Payment", but then to add a Payment, I would do `Lease.Add`, which isn't very intuitive. I'd rather add a payment by using `Lease.Payments.Add`, to keep things consistent with the built-in classes, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out the first part (more or less) by replacing the code for Lease with the following:  

    `Option Explicit`  
    `Private Payments As New Collection`  

    `Public Property Get Payments(Optional ByRef param As _`  
        `Variant) As Variant`  

    `If IsMissing(param) Then`  

        `Set Payments = oPayments`  

    `Else`  

        `Set Payments = oPayments.Item(param)`  
    
    `End If`  

    `End Property`  

The only downside is that the property needs to be a variant, so you don't get the snazzy drop-down lists. EDIT: Help I cannot newline.

Comment: For the second part, you can expose Payments as either a Public field or via a Property Let/Get statement.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to creating a "default property" for your class can be found [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx). It's kinda ugly, but it can be done.

I don't have a great answer for the second question other than to advise you to just create a variable in a module and set it on initialization:

```
Set Payments = Lease.Payments
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second part I don't think you can do it like the Range object. You could make a Leases collection class. Assume gLeases is a public variable holding all your leases.

```
Dim Payments as CPayments

Set Payments = gLeases.GetLeaseBySheet(ActiveSheet).Payments

Debug.Print Payments(1).PaymentNumber
```

I don't know how your filling your leases now, but you would need to load them all up so that your GetLeaseBySheet property can find the right one.